# Multixterm Focus

Tags: tcl, expect, xterm

How do I focus on a specific `xterm` window from within `multixterm` from a script file?

For example, I run multixterm from a file with the commands:
`set xtermNames {1 2}
xtermStartAll`
to open up two xterm windows named, respectively, 1 and 2. I want to print "Hello" on xterm 1, and "World" on xterm 2.

I know that `xtermSend` will send a string to all windows, but I would like to know how to send to just a single window.

Comment: I would recommend you look into using tmux or screen. This multixterm looks pretty creaky in comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it! One should use the `exp_send $spawn_id "Text"` command, where $spawn_id is the unique Spawn ID of the desired xterm window.